# how to make methods in category classes available to other classes?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to use a class I got from iosframeworks.com called `UIImage+ProportionalFill`.  I know it's a category extending `UIImage`, but when I try to use one of its methods in another class I get a message saying `no visible @interface for UIImage declares the selector 'nameOfWhateverMethodIWantToUse'`.  I'm not surprised to get an error, since there must be more to using it than dropping it into XCode, but how do I make the methods in the new category/class available to other classes?

Comment: When you say "dropping it into XCode" do you mean adding it to the project AND importing it?

Comment: Oh, dear.  I know those are two different things, but I don't know which one(s) I did.  That, however, is for another question....

Answer (score 4):

You just need to import your category in the class you like to use it...

```
#import "UIImage+ProportionalFill.h"
```

I usually do this in the header file.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler needs to be able to see the declaration of the methods, which should be in the category's header file. You must import the header file wherever you want to use the methods.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `#import` the header containing the method declaration(s) in each file that uses said methods.

Note tha the methos should be prefixed;  i.e. `-JDnameOfWhateverMethodIWantToUse`.

Note also that adding categories to framework classes willy nilly can easily lead to a rather awfully architected application that becomes difficult to refactor/maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you said, I think you just forgot to import it.

```
#import "UIImage+ProportionalFill.h"
```

Write it on the top of the .h file of the class where you want to use the method.